# why $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\\$

Tags: calculus, summation, geometric-progressions

Why $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\\$$ 
I know that $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}\\$$
can I use the above to derive the first result?

Comment: Your sums should begin with $k=0$, not $k=1$.

Comment: The result is true iff $\;|x|<1\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb C\;$ , **not** for *any* value of $\;x\;$

Answer (score 6):

One way you can see that this result is true with a substitution. Let $y = x^2$. Then $$ \begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k} =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^{k}  \\ = \frac{1}{1-y} \\ = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\end{align}$$ Making substitutions like this will become immensely useful when you get to Taylor Series.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x^2)^k $$

Comment: Why can i do it? I mean why i can put the x^2 instead of x?

Comment: You can do it term by term: $x^{2k} = (x^2)^k$. @Yagel

Comment: This is just one of the basic properties of exponents.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sum of even powers,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k}$$ and multiply it by $1+x$. You get the sum of all powers,
$$(1+x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(x^{2k}+x^{2k+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k}.$$

Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k}=\frac1{(1-x)(1+x)}.$$

Comment: @aaronmaroja was right.

Comment: I know, substitution does not give the answer to the question.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: why ?

Comment: It's a trick, it works because it converges to the same as the other one. To know why, one needs to show is a subsequence. Not saying is incorrect or anything. It's just not rigorous enough. (+1) to your answer.

Comment: IMO, the substitution approach is bulletproof, as writing $y^2$ instead of $x$ makes no difference nowhere. On the opposite this "factorization" approach requires that term-wise multiplies and merging of series be legitimate.

Comment: The substitution works here alright since $\;|x|<1\iff |x^2|=|x|^2<1\;$ and thus we can use the geometric series sum formula

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a matter of logic. You know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}.$

Of course, this is just shorthand notation for the more formal:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{x:\mathbb{R}}\left(|x|<1 \rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$

If this notation makes no sense to you, have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Rules_of_inference) wikipedia page.

Anyway, by uniform substitution, we deduce:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{x:\mathbb{R}}\left(|x^2|<1 \rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x^2)^k = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$$

But given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the following hold:

- $|x^2|<1 \iff |x|<1$
- $(x^2)^k = x^{2k}$

Therefore:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{x:\mathbb{R}}\left(|x|<1 \rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2k} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)$$